# When clicking on a link, show alert box?

Tags: javascript

so I just started to learn JavaScript. When I click on "Click Me!", my alert box does not pop up!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>JAVASCRIPT</title>

</head>
<body>

    <a href="#" id="anchor">Click Me!</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var anchor = getElementById('anchor');
        // or anchor = getElementsByTagName('a') then do ('a')[0]

        anchor.addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);

        function doSomething() {
            alert('clicked');
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's because you should use `document.getElementById` and not just `getElementById`... The Javascript engine just raises an ecception and stops the execution.

Comment: Don't waste your time on the DOM API. Use jQuery: http://jquery.com/.

Comment: Oops! Thanks. Also, does anybody know a good place to learn JavaScript? I'm using the JavaScript from NULL series by tutsplus, but I prefer something text based.

Comment: @knut Learning jQuery is almost like learning a different language than Javascript. I wouldn't recommend that for basic beginners.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Standards_Curriculum#JavaScript_core_skills

Comment: @knut — For a lot of things, jQuery is needless bloat, for a lot of other things it performs huge amounts of magic that hide what is really happening and leads to questions about trying to append `$('</div>`)` that could be largely avoided if the underlying API was understood.

Comment: I want to get JavaScript totally down and then move on to jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot `document.` on the line with `getElementById`:

```
 var anchor = document.getElementById('anchor');
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` is a method of the `document` object, not a global function.

Change it to `document.getElementById('anchor');`

(Do have a more useful fallback then `href="#"` though for a real page though)

Answer (score 0):

A quicker guerrilla style approach would be:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="alert('clicked')">Click Me!</a>
```

In general though adding inline JS code is discouraged since it impacts maintainability. This would be better. Notice is is not necessary to use document.getElementById() since you can get the element reference from 'this'.

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="my_function(this)">Click Me!</a>

<script>
my_function = function(elem) {
   //elem points to anchor element clicked
}
</script>
```